# An inequality about the Lelong number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

The definition of **Lelong** number of   a closed positive $(1,1)$-current $T$ in $\mathbb C^n$, is as follows, 
$$v(T,x,r)=\frac1{(\pi r^2)^{n-1}}\int_{B(x,r)}T\wedge\omega^{n-1},$$
where $\omega$ denotes the standard Euclidean Kaehler form on $\mathbb C^n$.

**Q**: For $r$ small enough, can we say that
$$v(T,x):=\lim_{s\to0}v(T,x,s)<v(T,x,r).$$